# How to plot in edges and routes on the same folium in osmnx

Tags: python, networkx, openstreetmap, folium, osmnx

I'm trying to plot edges and routes in an interactive map by using: `ox.plot_graph_folium` or `ox.plot_routes_folium`.

```py
# plot the street network with folium
m1 = ox.plot_graph_folium(G, popup_attribute="name", weight=2, color="#8b0000")
```

I can plot the edges or routes separately, However, is there any way I can plot the edges and routes on the same grape?
This is my ideal output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentations: [`plot_graph_folium`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.folium.plot_graph_folium) has the parameter `graph_map`, which is a `folium.folium.Map` object. As well, [`plot_route_folium`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.folium.plot_route_folium) has the parameter `route_map`, which is a `folium.folium.Map` object.
For both of these parameters the docs state:

> if not None, plot on this preexisting folium map object

So you simply need to call one of these methods and take the returned folium map, e.g. your `m1`, and pass it to the respective parameter while calling the other method.